# Use session component on custom CakePHP library/plugin

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I would like to know how to use CakePHP session component in a custom library.

Let say I have this class under Lib/MyCustomlib/custom.php

```
class Custom {


}
```

and I want to use session component like this:

```
class Custom {
  function foo(){
   $var = $this->Session->read('somesessionval');
  }
}
```

can I just call the component like this :

```
class Custom{
   public $component = array('Session');  

   function foo(){
    $var = $this->Session->read('somesessionval');
   } 
}
```

or .. ?

please share me your good answer senior cakephp fellas.

my cakephp version is 2.4 .

thanks!

Comment: Please always say in which version of cakephp

Answer (score 1):

[CakeSession](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-CakeSession.html) class provides some static methods to deal with session data:

```
CakeSession::read('somesessionval');
```

You must not use components from libraries.

> Components are packages of logic that are shared between controllers.
>   http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html

Comment: in my captcha component `CakeSession::read();` and `CakeSession::write();` was working but stopped working dont know when and why, now i checked it is not setting any session variable, what should I check